# Empty Reply from Openshift Origin Hosted Django Web Service when accessed from Outside of Openshift Cluster

Tags: django, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/sclorg/django-ex)
to set up an OpenShift Origin deployment of a Django project I'm working on. Everything seems to be working. There is a Pod running a service with a route set up and the service is exposed. However, when I browse to the website, I get an error that the connection was reset. Using curl:

```
curl http://my-openshift-website.com
```

results in

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Besides, I witness the following phenomena:

- I know the code that serves the index web page runs when I access it from my browser (or using curl) because when I add code to create an empty file when the '/' page is requested, I see in the pod's terminal that the file is indeed created.
- When I try to do the same curl command from the pod terminal (i.e. from within the cluster), everything works and I get the web page.
- The pod's log files don't register anything when I try to access the service from the web browser but do register access when I do so from the pod terminal.

Comment: Where are you deploying your application? In openshift cloud(free) or minishift? I have deployed Django application in minishift and private openshift cloud from this [Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ruddra/openshift-django/master/Dockerfile) without any issue.

Comment: What WSGI server are you running? When you curl the application from the pod, ensure you use ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080``. That will ensure you are using what is external IP and not localhost. This will show if you have ``ALLOWED_HOSTS`` set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake from my side. I am using an OpenShift cluster deployed by CERN (openshift.cern.ch). I didn't change the visibility setting from 'Intranet' to 'Internet' in 'Site Access and Permissions' in the 'Manage your CERN websites' page. There is an additional explanation about how this setting works:

> The above configuration page in Web Services manipulates the default
>   route in your Openshift project, i.e. the route where the Path
>   property is not defined (and the Host property matches the
>   webservices-assigned FQDN).
>
> When using multiple routes in a project and/or routes with a Path
>   property, each route's visibility is controlled independently via the
>   route annotation router.cern.ch/network-visibility. This annotation
>   currently accepts two values: Internet or Intranet. No annotation (or
>   any other value) is interpreted as Intranet, i.e. route will only be
>   reachable from the CERN network.
>
> Annotations can be manipulated via the oc annotate CLI command, e.g.
>   oc annotate route my-route router.cern.ch/network-visibility=Intranet

Answer (score 0):

was it only because of the annotation or DNS mapping can also contribute to such behaviour

also can be also explain the annotation you mentioned because i tried looking for these annotation https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#route-specific-annotations but could not find